# USB keyboard not recognized by motherboard with only a legacy PS/2 header

Tags: usb, keyboard, bios

I've bought a [D945GSEJT](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-d945gsejt.html) Atom motheboard that has three usb ports available and no PS/2 connector, just a PS/2 header.

I have a PS/2 keyboard with a PS/2 to USB adapter and connected it to a USB port. I tried all three USB ports. The problem is that the board seems to not recognize my keyboard. None of the keys I press are detected by the system.

I've read that maybe I could try to change BIOS USB settings to solve this detection problem.
But how can I do it if I can't type anything? Is there any other option other than buying a PS/2 adapter and plug it to the PS/2 header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could borrow a standard USB keyboard - that should work. Once you can get into the bios you can enable legacy USB keyboard/mouse and that should sort out your PS2 keyboard with adapter.

Comment: BJ292: Had to drive a few kilometers to find an USB keyboard and the motherboard works with it. But, legacy USB was enabled. Still, after boot, PS/2 keyboard with usb adapter doesn't work.  Why this difference in behavior between the two types of keyboards?

Comment: Just to ensure completeness, the PS/2 keyboard with USB adapter doesn't work because it's connected to a KVM switch. When I connect it directly to the computer, it works fine.